# Database structure when table can relate to other tables - but should only relate to one at the time

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My Vehicle table holds some info that could regard both a bus and a car. But I also need specific data for a bus - or a car.

Would it be right to do this:

```
Table Vehicle
Bus_id (ref key)
Car_id (ref key)

Table Bus

Table Car
```

Then Vehicle could reference car and bus the same time, which it should not.

Or like so:

```
Table Vehicle

Table Bus
Vehicle_id (ref key)

Table Car
Vehicle_id (ref key)
```

But again, a bus and a car could at the same time reference the same vehicle info.

How can I accomplish that a vehicle info, if it has specific data, only relates then to either a bus or a car?

Comment: Any reason why these three tables can't be merged into one?

Comment: No do not add a column for each type of vehicle to your vehicle table. That is a bad way to go. Instead you should add VehicleType in your Vehicle table so you know what type of vehicle it is. You coule eliminate the issue of having the same ID from a bus and a car by using a sequence so that every vehicle has a unique ID regardless of the type.

Comment: @SeanLange This is not just to define Vehicle type, but also because Bus tables has bus related data, likewise Car table has car related data. Otherwise I would have used VehicleType in Vehicle.

Comment: @e4c5 I would like to show tables of busses and cars. And when clicked a bus (or a car) then show specific bus (or car) info, but also show whats in Vehicle, for that specific bus (or car). If merged into one, I would have to have alot of business or UI logic to seperate them. Hope it makes sense

Comment: what are these car related and bus related data?

Comment: @e4c5 Just specific bus/car data. This is just an example. Think boat / car maybe in stead if you think that bus/car shares too much similiar data  :)

Comment: If you want good answers post some sample data

Comment: @e4c5 Why should that be relevant to my question? It would be way to difficult for my to post my entire project here, but my example sums it up perfectly. And yes, bus, car, boat - what ever needs to be a table for their own.

Comment: To be honest this probably a really case for a partial EAV design. You could normalize Vehicle and VehicleType. Then one more table to define the properties of each type. Last but not least an EAV table that contains the properties. It will require some thinking and dynamic sql to extract the data but it once you build it would be pretty easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

If you want SQL server to help enforce this, you could go with a vehicle table that points to either bus or car, as in your first example, and use a check constraint and filtered indexes to accomplish this:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE (
   [VEHICLE_RECID] integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   [BusID] integer NULL REFERENCES [BUS] ([BUS_RECID]),
   [CarID] integer NULL REFERENCES [CAR] ([CAR_RECID]),
   CONSTRAINT [CK_VEHICLE_OnlyCarOrBus] CHECK (
      ([BusID] IS NULL AND [CarID] IS NOT NULL) 
      OR ([BusID] IS NOT NULL AND [CarID] IS NULL))
));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [BusID] ON VEHICLE ([BusID]) WHERE [BusID] IS NOT NULL
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [CarID] ON VEHICLE ([CarID]) WHERE [CarID] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution Tim. That seems to do the work. But you also kindly imply that it might not be the right thing to do? If so, what would you then do if I may ask? (move it up to business logic?)

Comment: While this will work consider how this is going to get when you add more vehicle types. This is not a well normalized solution.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand - and agree. Could you help me in the right direction of what then could be a well normalized solution? Best regards